# Map values to separate column - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to map values from a column to a separate column. Using below, the `calculate_distances` function measures the distance from each point to the nearest point for each `Group`. I also return the index value of each point for identification.

This all works fine. But instead of the index value, I'm hoping to map the corresponding `ID` value within the function to the output.

If I don't map the ID values across, both `nearest_object` cols will display the index value, instead of the actual `ID` value.

I'll comment out my attempt to show the output.

```
from sklearn.neighbors import BallTree
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({              
    'Time' : [1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2],             
    'ID' : ['A','B','C','X','U','V','A','B','C','X','U','V'],      
    'Group' : ['Red','Red','Red','Grn','Grn','Grn','Red','Red','Red','Grn','Grn','Grn'],           
    'X' : [2.0,3.0,4.0,2.0,2.0,1.0,1.0,6.0,4.0,2.0,5.0,3.0],
    'Y' : [3.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,2.0,1.0,2.0,0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0,0.0],           
    })

def calculate_distances(df, group_column='Group'):    

    '''
    Calculate distance and id to both red and green groups.
    '''
    # unq groups
    groups = df[group_column].unique()

    all_points = df[['X','Y']].values

    for group in groups:
        group_points = df[df[group_column] == group][['X','Y']]
    
        # calculate distance between points
        tree = BallTree(group_points, leaf_size=15, metric='minkowski')

        distance, index = tree.query(all_points, k=1)
        distances = distance[:,0]
        nearest_id = group_points.index[index[:,0]]
                    
        distance_column_name = "distance_{}".format( group )
        df[ distance_column_name ] = distances
    
        distance_column_nearest_name = "nearest_object_{}".format( group )
        df[distance_column_nearest_name] = nearest_id   

    # map ID values
    #df.iloc[:,-3] = df.iloc[:,-3].map(df.set_index('index')['ID']) 
    #df.iloc[:,-1] = df.iloc[:,-1].map(df.set_index('index')['ID'])       

    return df

df = df.groupby(['Time']).apply(calculate_distances).reset_index()
```

out:

```
    Time ID Group    X    Y  distance_Red  nearest_object_Red  distance_Grn  nearest_object_Grn
0      1  A   Red  2.0  3.0      0.000000                   0      1.000000                   4
1      1  B   Red  3.0  1.0      0.000000                   1      1.414214                   3
2      1  C   Red  4.0  0.0      0.000000                   2      2.000000                   3
3      1  X   Grn  2.0  0.0      1.414214                   1      0.000000                   3
4      1  U   Grn  2.0  2.0      1.000000                   0      0.000000                   4
5      1  V   Grn  1.0  1.0      2.000000                   1      0.000000                   5
6      2  A   Red  1.0  2.0      0.000000                   6      1.414214                   9
7      2  B   Red  6.0  0.0      0.000000                   7      1.000000                  10
8      2  C   Red  4.0  1.0      0.000000                   8      1.414214                  10
9      2  X   Grn  2.0  1.0      1.414214                   6      0.000000                   9
10     2  U   Grn  5.0  0.0      1.000000                   7      0.000000                  10
11     2  V   Grn  3.0  0.0      1.414214                   8      0.000000                  11
```

intended output:

```
    Time ID Group    X    Y  distance_Red nearest_object_Red  distance_Grn nearest_object_Grn
0      1  A   Red  2.0  3.0      0.000000                  A      1.000000                  U
1      1  B   Red  3.0  1.0      0.000000                  B      1.414214                  X
2      1  C   Red  4.0  0.0      0.000000                  C      2.000000                  X
3      1  X   Grn  2.0  0.0      1.414214                  B      0.000000                  X
4      1  U   Grn  2.0  2.0      1.000000                  A      0.000000                  U
5      1  V   Grn  1.0  1.0      2.000000                  B      0.000000                  V
6      2  A   Red  1.0  2.0      0.000000                  A      1.414214                  X
7      2  B   Red  6.0  0.0      0.000000                  B      1.000000                  U
8      2  C   Red  4.0  1.0      0.000000                  C      1.414214                  U
9      2  X   Grn  2.0  1.0      1.414214                  A      0.000000                  X
10     2  U   Grn  5.0  0.0      1.000000                  B      0.000000                  U
11     2  V   Grn  3.0  0.0      1.414214                  C      0.000000                  V
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand, but if you add the parameter `drop=True` in the last `reset_index`, it gives the expected output. try `df=df.groupby(['Time']).apply(calculate_distances).reset_index(drop=True)`, is it what you want?

Comment: I've added more detail. Does it make sense now?

Comment: Now that you removed the `df=df.reset_index()` in your function, the mapping in the function can be done with `df.iloc[:,-3] = df.iloc[:,-3].map(df['ID'])` (same for the other column) and in your last line of code outside the function, you remove the `reset_index`, by doing so I get your expected output I think

Comment: Yeh, I've currently got it outside the function but I'm hoping to pass everything inside the function, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the index is named `Time` while the dataframe already has a column with the same name. When you do `reset_index`, pandas try to make the index a normal column, in this case it fails due to the duplicate name. Try:

```
df = df.groupby(['Time']).apply(calculate_distances).reset_index(drop=True)
```